# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable. While the Error line is working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my code, I call this function `ReVerseShiftRowMK2`, and the appending function would not work. I then try to print the List to try and debug it, and suddenly it works? However, it is still giving me ERROR(TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable).

I think it have something  to do with <function reVersedMixCol at 0x000002392B1100D8>?

Here is the console

```
HERE1 ['4f', '4f', '86', '16', '11', '49', '07', 'ce', '08', '8b', '4f', 'd3', '44', 'db', '50', 'e8']
HERE2 ce
HERE1 <function reVersedMixCol at 0x000002142F820168>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/me the commie/Documents/!School/Computer science/New folder/AES encryption.py", line 806, in <module>
    print(DESCRYSubAESHex(S, KeyScheldule(Key_HEX_list, 10)))
  File "c:/Users/me the commie/Documents/!School/Computer science/New folder/AES encryption.py", line 779, in DESCRYSubAESHex
    SubHex1 = ReVerseShiftRowMK2(SubHex1)
  File "c:/Users/me the commie/Documents/!School/Computer science/New folder/AES encryption.py", line 490, in ReVerseShiftRowMK2
    print(("HERE2 " + str(Box4x4[7])))
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

and here is the function

```py
def ReVerseShiftRowMK2(Box4x4):
    
    print("HERE1 " + str(Box4x4))
    Row1 = []
    Row2 = []
    Row3 = []
    Row4 = []
    print(("HERE2 " + str(Box4x4[7])))

    for a in range(4):
        Row1.append(Box4x4[a + 0])
        Row2.append(Box4x4[a + 4])
        Row3.append(Box4x4[a + 8])
        Row4.append(Box4x4[a + 12])

####### more code #############
```

This function is called in:

```py
def DESCRYSubAESHex(SubHex1, FullKey):

    #print(SubHex1)
    #print(FullKey)
    for a in range(16):
        #print(SubHex1[a])
        #print(FullKey[0][a])
        SubHex1[a] = xor_strings(SubHex1[a],FullKey[len(FullKey) - 1][a])         

    for a in range(len(FullKey) - 2):  # 0 to 13
        #print(SubHex1)
        SubHex1 = ReVerseShiftRowMK2(SubHex1)
       

        SubHex1 = reVeredSBox(SubHex1)

      

        for b in range(16):
            SubHex1[b] = xor_strings(SubHex1[b],FullKey[(len(FullKey) - 2) - a][b])       
        
        SubHex1 = reVersedMixCol

    SubHex1 = ReVerseShiftRowMK2(SubHex1)

    SubHex1 = reVeredSBox(SubHex1)

    for b in range(16):
        SubHex1[b] = xor_strings(SubHex1[b],FullKey[0][b]) 

    

    return SubHex1

print(DESCRYSubAESHex(S, A))
```

S is a 16index array

A is a 2d array consisting of 10 by 16

```
([][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][])
([][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][])
([][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][])
...
down to 10
```

Comment: Where is the line that calls `ReVerseShiftRowMK2()`

Comment: Provide [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get the question answered.

Comment: I ran it in console, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Show full code please. I think you gave `reVersedMixCol ` as parameter to `ReVerseShiftRowMK2`

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening is this function is being run multiple times. The first time it is run, you passed in the right thing, an array. So it correctly prints.

The second time, presumably this line: `SubHex1 = ReVerseShiftRowMK2(SubHex1)`, you passed in a function. So that's why this was printed:

```
<function reVersedMixCol at 0x000002392B1100D8>
```

because of this line:

```
print(Box4x4)
```

Then, when it got to this line:

```
print(Box4x4[7])
```

It errored out. So I would look into that SubHex variable from above.
And like Inyoung Kim said, this SubHex variable is probably a reference to the ReVerseMixCol function

Comment: Thank you i found what was wrong. at line    SubHex1 = reVersedMixCol i didn't write in (Subhex1)

Answer (score 0):

in function declaration `def DESCRYSubAESHex(SubHex1, FullKey)`

```
    for b in range(16):
        SubHex1[b] = xor_strings(SubHex1[b],FullKey[(len(FullKey) - 2) - a][b])       
        
    SubHex1 = reVersedMixCol

SubHex1 = ReVerseShiftRowMK2(SubHex1)

SubHex1 = reVeredSBox(SubHex1)
```

1. you assigned `reVersedMixCol` to the variable `SubHex1`
2. then you passed `SubHex1` to `ReverseShiftRowMK2`
3. Inside `ReverseShiftRowMK2`, you are trying to access `index 7` of `Box4x4` which actually contains a function. This is why error `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable` is thrown. Meaning `you can't index on to functions`